# How to use a custom activation function in keras R API

Tags: r, keras

I am coding with keras R API and I need to develop a custom function for my activation function such as a(x)=10*x, not the the usual ones such as sigmoid or tanh

```
model %>%
  # Creates dense embedding layer; outputs 3D tensor
  # with shape (batch_size, sequence_length, output_dim)
  layer_embedding(input_dim = 500, 
                  output_dim = 30, 
                  input_length = ncol(ttrainx)) %>% 
  #bidirectional(layer_lstm(units = 64)) %>%
  layer_lstm(units = 10) %>% 
  layer_dropout(rate = 0.5) %>% 
  layer_dense(units =2, activation = 'sigmoid')
```

Do anyone know how I can write a custom activation function?